# someone please explain this

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

we have a finite measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ and collection of real measurable function {$f_{\alpha}:\Omega \to R$ where $\alpha \in I$} also we have a convex function $\Phi(x)$ which satisfies the following conditions
(1) $\Phi(0)=0$
(2) $\Phi(-x)=\Phi(x)$
(3) $\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}\uparrow \infty$ as $x \uparrow \infty$

so I am doing some proof and I am stuck in the below step
$\int_{\Omega}\Phi(f_\alpha)d\mu$=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n-1<|f_\alpha|<n}\Phi(|f_\alpha|)d\mu$
$\hspace{2cm}$ $\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Phi(n)\mu(n-1\leq|f_\alpha|<n)$
$\hspace{2cm}$ $\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[\Phi(n+1)-\Phi(n)]\mu(|f_{\alpha}|\geq n)$..............(A)

Can someone explain how we got (A) above

Comment: Please [choose a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

Comment: It looks like they are trying to switch the sums, although they might be neglecting some terms.  If we define $q_n=\mu(|f|\geq n)$ then $\mu(n-1\leq |f|<n)=q_{n-1}-q_n$ and we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_n(q_{n-1}-q_n)$ and we know by a telescoping series argument that $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \phi_n(q_{n-1}-q_n) = \phi_1q_0 - \phi_mq_m + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} q_i(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)$$ It seems they are neglecting the $\phi_1q_0$ term. Also the limiting behavior of $\phi_mq_m$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ is important, but you can argue that $-\phi_mq_m\leq 0$ for all $m$ so it can be removed for a bound.

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\Phi(N)q_N\ge\Phi(1)\mu(\Omega)$ then it works.